# How to use dynamic module loading in an onion architecture using MVC4 as frontend

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, onion-architecture

I'm trying to wrap my head around dependency injection in the [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), I've found [this solution](http://onionarch.codeplex.com/) which uses a dependency resolution layer around the onion. But there is so much going on that I'm completely lost.

So I setup a project to try it out. I like to start off simple, so a simple log entry on a (MVC) controller method would be a good start.
I'd like to use [Dynamic Module Loading](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) (`kernel.Load("*.dll");`) since it comes recommended from the Ninject wiki.

My solution looks like this: (For now)

```
Solution
- Core.Services
- Infrastructure.Logging
- DependencyResolution
- UI.MVC (default internet template)
```

I'd like to follow the guides lines for dependency resolution outlined [here](http://eohmicrosoft.blogspot.dk/2012/08/laying-it-out-onion-architecture.html).

[image]

**Ilogger**

```
namespace Core.Services
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(string message);
    }
}
```

**Logging Implementation**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Logging
{
    public class DebugLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Log(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Dependency Resolution**

```
namespace DependencyResolution
{
    public class TestModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ILogger>().To<DebugLogger>();
        }
    }
}
```

### What I want to accomplish

**UI**

```
namespace UI.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            _logger.Log("It works!");

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to run `kernel.Load("*.dll");` somehow and I need to setup my MVC to use DI. I'm just now sure how since the UI cannot know about the Dependency Resolution layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DI container should be composed somewhere. This place is called the `composition root` and is the outermost layer. In your case that would be the ASP.NET MVC application. So saying that it should not know about the DI simply doesn't make sense. The Ninject.MVC3 package comes with a custom dependency resolver implementation that gets plugged into the application and you will get automatic DI in your controllers.

Comment: That's what's confusing me as well but look at this http://eohmicrosoft.blogspot.dk/2012/08/laying-it-out-onion-architecture.html and the solution I linked the UI layer doesn't know about outer resolution layer. So ye you and me both are confused :D

Comment: In this diagram `UI`, doesn't mean `ASP.NET MVC`. It means the `V` of your ASP.NET MVC. That's the UI. The ASP.NET host is the place to configure your dependency injection framework. Ideally this is done in the `Application_Start` event. So I guess what confuses you here (because personally I do not feel confused about that) is the notion of *layer*. You confuse your ASP.NET MVC application with a layer in the onion architecture. Please read about the composition root which is the place to configure your DI container: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: And I am quoting you from his post: `In ASP.NET MVC applications it's global.asax and a custom IControllerFactory`. Just to mention, the author of this blog post is Mark Seemann, author of the [`Dependency Injection in .NET book`](http://manning.com/seemann/).

Comment: Right on the money. I actually did think that the entire MVC project was the UI part of the architecture.

Comment: No, that's where your confusion comes from.